# Adding a column in pandas using a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to understand the difference between these two statements

```
dataframe['newColumn'] = 'stringconst'
```

and

```
for x in y:
   if x=="value":
      csv = pd.read_csv(StringIO(table), header=None, names=None)
      dataframe['newColumn'] = csv[0]
```

In the first case pandas populates all the rows with the constant value, but in the second case it populates only the first row and assigns NaN to rest of the rows. Why is this? How can I assign the value in the second case to all the rows in the dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

Because `csv[0]` is *not a scalar value*. It's a `pd.Series`, and when you do assignment with `pd.Series` it tries to align by index (the whole point of `pandas`), and probably it's getting `NAN` everywhere except the first row because only the first-row's index aligns with the `pd.DataFrame`  index. So, consider two data-frames (note, they are copies except for the index, which is shifted by 20):

```
>>> df
   0  1  2  3  4
0  4 -5 -1  0  3
1 -2 -2  1  3  4
2  1  2  4  4 -4
3 -5  2 -3 -5  1
4 -5 -3  1  1 -1
5 -4  0  4 -3 -4
6 -2 -5 -3  1  0
7  4  0  0 -4 -4
8 -4  4 -2 -5  4
9  1 -2  4  3  0
>>> df2
    0  1  2  3  4
20  4 -5 -1  0  3
21 -2 -2  1  3  4
22  1  2  4  4 -4
23 -5  2 -3 -5  1
24 -5 -3  1  1 -1
25 -4  0  4 -3 -4
26 -2 -5 -3  1  0
27  4  0  0 -4 -4
28 -4  4 -2 -5  4
29  1 -2  4  3  0
>>> df['new'] = df[1]
>>> df
   0  1  2  3  4  new
0  4 -5 -1  0  3   -5
1 -2 -2  1  3  4   -2
2  1  2  4  4 -4    2
3 -5  2 -3 -5  1    2
4 -5 -3  1  1 -1   -3
5 -4  0  4 -3 -4    0
6 -2 -5 -3  1  0   -5
7  4  0  0 -4 -4    0
8 -4  4 -2 -5  4    4
9  1 -2  4  3  0   -2
>>> df['new2'] = df2[1]
>>> df
   0  1  2  3  4  new  new2
0  4 -5 -1  0  3   -5   NaN
1 -2 -2  1  3  4   -2   NaN
2  1  2  4  4 -4    2   NaN
3 -5  2 -3 -5  1    2   NaN
4 -5 -3  1  1 -1   -3   NaN
5 -4  0  4 -3 -4    0   NaN
6 -2 -5 -3  1  0   -5   NaN
7  4  0  0 -4 -4    0   NaN
8 -4  4 -2 -5  4    4   NaN
9  1 -2  4  3  0   -2   NaN
```

So, one thing you can do to assign the *whole column* is to simply assign the *values*:

```
>>> df
   0  1  2  3  4  new  new2
0  4 -5 -1  0  3   -5   NaN
1 -2 -2  1  3  4   -2   NaN
2  1  2  4  4 -4    2   NaN
3 -5  2 -3 -5  1    2   NaN
4 -5 -3  1  1 -1   -3   NaN
5 -4  0  4 -3 -4    0   NaN
6 -2 -5 -3  1  0   -5   NaN
7  4  0  0 -4 -4    0   NaN
8 -4  4 -2 -5  4    4   NaN
9  1 -2  4  3  0   -2   NaN
>>> df['new2'] = df2[1].values
>>> df
   0  1  2  3  4  new  new2
0  4 -5 -1  0  3   -5    -5
1 -2 -2  1  3  4   -2    -2
2  1  2  4  4 -4    2     2
3 -5  2 -3 -5  1    2     2
4 -5 -3  1  1 -1   -3    -3
5 -4  0  4 -3 -4    0     0
6 -2 -5 -3  1  0   -5    -5
7  4  0  0 -4 -4    0     0
8 -4  4 -2 -5  4    4     4
9  1 -2  4  3  0   -2    -2
```

Or, if you want to assign *the first value in the first column*, then *actually select the first value* using `iloc` or another selector and *then* do assignment:

```
>>> df
   0  1  2  3  4  new  new2
0  4 -5 -1  0  3   -5    -5
1 -2 -2  1  3  4   -2    -2
2  1  2  4  4 -4    2     2
3 -5  2 -3 -5  1    2     2
4 -5 -3  1  1 -1   -3    -3
5 -4  0  4 -3 -4    0     0
6 -2 -5 -3  1  0   -5    -5
7  4  0  0 -4 -4    0     0
8 -4  4 -2 -5  4    4     4
9  1 -2  4  3  0   -2    -2
>>> df['newest'] = df2.iloc[0,0]
>>> df
   0  1  2  3  4  new  new2  newest
0  4 -5 -1  0  3   -5    -5       4
1 -2 -2  1  3  4   -2    -2       4
2  1  2  4  4 -4    2     2       4
3 -5  2 -3 -5  1    2     2       4
4 -5 -3  1  1 -1   -3    -3       4
5 -4  0  4 -3 -4    0     0       4
6 -2 -5 -3  1  0   -5    -5       4
7  4  0  0 -4 -4    0     0       4
8 -4  4 -2 -5  4    4     4       4
9  1 -2  4  3  0   -2    -2       4
```